# show the result of type erasure in java

Tags: java, type-erasure

Is there a way to display type erasure in java? I mean to see how code will look like after type erasure?

For example to show that

```
List<? extends Number> a; //before
List a; //after
```

or

```
class Node<T extends Number> { 
   private T variable; 
}
```

become

```
 class Node { 
     private Number variable; 
 }
```

and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just compile the code and use javap:

javap -c com.mypackage.MyClass

Or you can use this plugin for Eclipse: http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html